# Installing Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, reboot

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop（windows7）, now the Ubuntu installing wizard just show me： Reboot or manually reboot later. If I choose to reboot, does that mean I will lost all of my work and photo on my driver C?
Thank you

Comment: Are you using wubi installer ?

Comment: yes i got it from wubi

Comment: while installing, did you select any empty drive ?

Comment: I only have one drive on my laptop. All on drive C.

Comment: If you are not deviating from the instructions given [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows), nothing will happen to your c drive contents :)

Answer (score 2):

There are **three** possibilities :

1) Installed in **Non DOS (free) partition** : Your work will **remain** as it is. No need to worry.

2) Installed in **c drive** after selecting option - install ubuntu **with window**s : Your work will **remain** as it is. No need to worry.

3)  Installed in **c drive** after selecting option - install ubuntu **on entire c drive** :You will **loose your data**.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry you will lose nothing

Comment: Your answer is not specific. It doesn't cover all the scenarios. Try to answer after considering each and every possibility before answering the question.

Comment: He said that he used Wubi, so the installation has been finished. He have already chosen a place in the hard disk, so nothing to be lost